# NServiceBus IHandleTimeouts throws SagaNotFoundHandlers

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus3

I am trying to use the NServiceBus 3.0 ITimeoutState and IHandleTimeouts feature in my Saga. I have the following code snip. The following code working fine without any issue on NServiceBus.3.0.0-rc5. But, when i updated the DLLs with any version > 3.0.0 the saga timeout is not working as expected and it is throwing the following warning!

2012-04-05 09:15:26,267 [Worker.5] INFO  NServiceBus.Sagas.Impl.SagaDispatcherFactory [(null)] <(null)> - Could not find a saga for the message type SomeNameSpace.MySagaTimeout with id 9496c29e-f745-4ada-8212-99e47324922b\20920. Going to invoke **SagaNotFoundHandlers**.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

**The TimeoutMessage:**

```
public class MySagaTimeout : ITimeoutState
{
    public InputMessage1 Source { get; set; }
}
```

**The Saga Code:**

```
public class BrandMerchandisingRoot : Saga<MySagaState>,
                                          IAmStartedByMessages<InputMessage1>,
                                          IHandleTimeouts<MySagaTimeout>,
                                          IHandleMessages<MySagaTimeout>
{
      public void Handle(InputMessage1 message)
      {
        RequestUtcTimeout(5.Seconds(), new MySagaTimeout {Source = message});
      }

      public void Timeout(MySagaTimeout state)
      {
        //some other code here
      }

      public void Handle(MySagaTimeout message)
      {
         Timeout(message);
      }
}
```

**The Configuration:**

```
Configure.With()
.StructureMapBuilder(ObjectFactory.Container)
.RunTimeoutManager()
.UseInMemoryTimeoutPersister()
.MsmqSubscriptionStorage()
.Sagas()
.UnicastBus();
```

NOTE: I am using my own saga persister and I have the implementation for 
*IFindSagas<MySagaState>.Using<MySagaTimeout>*

Comment: IHandleMessages<MySagaTimeout> I added later to check if it helps!

Comment: When a timeout arrives the infrastructure is calling the ISagaPersister.Get<T>(sagaId) so the IFindSagas won't help you. Can you set a breakpoint in your own persister to make sure that it's beeing called?

Comment: Yes! That did all the magic. It worked perfectly. Thanks for the hint. Sorry for updating my feedback late.

Comment: Press "answer your own question" and put that in the answer. Then click accept answer, so that it becomes marked with the green checkmark.